# How to run multiple classes sequentially in TestNG.xml?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

I have 2 classes in the same package which I need to run sequentially, ie, only after executing my 1st class should my 2nd class start executing. Right now, when I run my xml, 2 browsers are opening up at the same time. I tried giving parallel=false, but not working. Below is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BasicSuite" parallel="false">
  <test name="TPR Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="pulse.tpr.ClockinToClockout"/>
      <class name="pulse.tpr.RightNowToClockout"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the following:

```
parallel="instances" thread-count="1"
```

And extra if you want to run in a specific order inside a class, you can use the following.

```
@Test
public void Test1() {

}

@Test (dependsOnMethods={"Test1"})
public void Test2() {

}

@Test (dependsOnMethods={"Test2"})
public void Test3() {

}
```

However this will work just inside your class. You can't assign a method from another class.